# How to calculate average using jq from JSON output

Tags: json, average, jq

This is the exact JSON for which i am trying to parse with jq to get an average

```
{
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T18:35:00Z",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "ExtendedStatistics": {
                "p80": 7.39284928374
            }
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T18:00:00Z",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "ExtendedStatistics": {
                "p80": 2.234234
            }
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T18:45:00Z",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "ExtendedStatistics": {
                "p80": 2.4567
            }
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T18:50:00Z",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "ExtendedStatistics": {
                "p80": 2.0
            }
        },

        {
            "Timestamp": "2020-02-20T18:20:00Z",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "ExtendedStatistics": {
                "p80": 2.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using `.Datapoints[]|select(.ExtendedStatistics.p80 >=0  )| [.ExtendedStatistics.p80] | @tsv` 
gives me

```
"7.39284928374"
"2.234234"
"2.4567"
"2"
"2"
```

I am trying to get an average of all the numbers
How do i get a single number as output 
**Expected Output**

```
3.216756656748
```

Calculated as

```
Average:    16.08378328374 / 5 = 3.216756656748
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a single array instead of an array per entry, then pipe it to the filter add and the filter length, which will add the numbers in the array and compute the length of the array. FInally, you divide the results of both filters and... voila!

```
jq '[.Datapoints[] | select(.ExtendedStatistics.p80>=0) | .ExtendedStatistics.p80] | add/length' file.json
```

Comment: With `[ .Datapoints[].ExtendedStatistics.p80 | select(. >= 0) ] | add / length` you can save some characters